# How do I add friends?

Tags: happy-street

I play Happy Street on my Macbook Pro - I am having trouble finding a way to connect it to my Facebook account. All the online help says "click the add your friends button..."

Is this a button within the Happy Street app itself?

If so - I don't have an add friends button on my happy street game. Or if it is through the game center... my friend requests are not being received. No idea how to add friends... it is very sad.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You know when you click on the shopping button? If you look down there, the friends button is down there. You click on that and down at the bottom it says type in username or add someone from Facebook.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Facebook, then under Settings, go to the Apps and search for Happy Street. Go ahead and connect with it.